# Checking if value exists in firebase subcollection document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query Cloud Firestore for a specific id within a sub collection using JavaScript. Given the broadcaster's name, I need to check if the broadcaster's requestQueue already contains an id (such as `4Sav8RLaXMBpTZX6xNPj0k`).

```
+users
+broadcasters   
  .pikachu
  .charmander
     +requestQueue
       .2VbP451HVadLkGePEdyh
         -id:"2Fxmhks0bxGSBdJ92vM42m"
       .HQ8djbqCue9c0HWs2bTQ
         -id:"7pp0hwaR212kgDLNcUYVsC"
       .FuN8p8n76Bf5iL7izwHq
         -id:"4Sav8RLaXMBpTZX6xNPj0K"
  .bulbasaur
+viewers
```

Collections are denoted with a `+` sign and documents are denoted with a `.` sign. Fields are denoted with a dash `-` sign.

How would I check if an id already exists in the broadcaster's requestQueue?

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward query.  What have you tried?  Is there some code that isn't working the way you expect?  Have you consulted the documentation for querying Cloud Firestore?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries